# Sales Force Admin

Tags: admin, system-admin

Where to start to learn to become a Salesforce Administrator.
Im new to software but have an idea about allt he technologies and differences in industry.

Can you guys give me pointers

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This type of question doesn't work so well here. In general, the more specific and detailed you can be, the better. Outside of using your search engine of choice to look for blogs and other resources, https://trailhead.salesforce.com is _the_ go-to (and official) resource for learning about Salesforce.